# Converting javascript dictionary to array/object to be passed in jquery.params

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

I have a javascript variable which is a dictionary of key-values pairs of querystring. I need to again convert this dictionary into a query string. I am using jquery.param functin but it takes either an array or an object. How can I convert my dictinoary variable to array/object which jquery.params can accept.

Tried using serializeArray but it does not work.

Comment: Could you add an example of the code you're using to initialise this dictionary? Both of our answers involve making certain assumptions about your code! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) method can take an array i in this form:

```
[{ name: 'asdf', value: '42' },{ name: 'qwerty', value: '1337' }]
```

If your dictionary have other property names, you can use the [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method to convert it. Example:

```
arr = $.map(arr, function(e){
  return { name: e.key, value: e.val };
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question right (some code samples would help!) by "dictionary" you mean a construction like:

```
var dict = { key1: value1, key2: value2 … }
```

or:

```
var dict = {};
dict[key1] = value1;
dict[key2] = value2;
```

or possibly:

```
var dict = {};
dict.key1 = value1;
dict.key2 = value2;
```

If so, you should know that *all* of these are doing the same thing, i.e. setting properties on JavaScript objects, and should be serialised correctly by `jQuery.param`. Succinctly, JavaScript objects ≈ dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

use Object.values() :

```
var arr = Object.values(some_dict)
```